# split mysql database field into 2 parts

Tags: mysql

i am saving complete file path in single field now i want to split it. bellow is my current database file path.
Current field name is "video_thumb"

```
../files/thumbs/2014-Oct/1413648778-sm.jpg
```

now i want to split it into 2 fields
folder path in one field 
i want to split the following to "thumb_path"

```
../files/thumbs/2014-Oct/
```

the file name in another field "file_name"

```
1413648778-sm.jpg
```

Comment: You say `thumb_path` and `file_name` but there are no references to this in your code.

Comment: currently it save in one field "video_thumb" i want to split it into 2 fields. the paths in  "thumb_path" filed and the file name to "file_name" field.

i will create 2 new fields for it with name thumb_path and file_name

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @STR = '../files/thumbs/2014-Oct/1413648778-sm.jpg';

SELECT  @STR,
            REVERSE(@STR) AS REVERSESTR,
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@STR),1,INSTR(REVERSE(@STR),'/') - 1)) FILENAME,
            REPLACE
            (@STR,
            REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@STR),1,INSTR(REVERSE(@STR),'/')  -1))
            ,''
            ) AS THUMB;
```

I have left all the steps in to illustrate the solution

Comment: Date uploaded **2014-Oct** and 
filename **1413648778-sm.jpg**
 are unique and 5000 records in database .. 

i want to split it.

and i am not coder ...

Answer (score 0):

Try with a query like this :

```
select '/files/thumbs/2014-Oct/1413648778-sm.jpg' path_and_filename,
       replace('/files/thumbs/2014-Oct/1413648778-sm.jpg', substring_index('/files/thumbs/2014-Oct/1413648778-sm.jpg', '/', -1), '') path,
       substring_index('/files/thumbs/2014-Oct/1413648778-sm.jpg', '/', -1) filename
from myTable
```

You will have 3 fields :

1. path_and_filename : Original Data
2. path : Only path string
3. filename : Only filename string

XaV